# Error occur in songs package

Tags: songs

Here i have taken the LaTeX code from songs package manual

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\noversenumbers
\begin{document}
\songsection{Worship Songs}
\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Doxology}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken}, sr={Revelation 5:13}, cr={Public domain.}]
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav’n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

earlier it is used to run successfully without any error but after updating packages it is showing error messages as shown below
[image]

Comment: That is a bug in the songs package. Notify the author. The line `\IfFileExists{ifpdf.sty}{\RequirePackage{ifpdf}\ifpdf\SB@pdftrue\fi}` is not a good idea ...

Comment: How to notify the author since there is no email ID @Ulrike Fischer

Comment: The catalogue shows a homepage and a repo: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/songs

Comment: There is no contact to send him, may be he is having account in https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/28900/kevin-hamlen  when author show the problem may be he will rectify the bugs@UlrikeFischer

Comment: On the home page there is a large button called "contact".

Comment: There is no author contact, the webmaster and ctan contact is given @UlrikeFischer

Comment: There is an email and a link to the home page of the author at http://songs.sourceforge.net/contact.html

Comment: Thank you so much@UlrikeFischer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You solve the issue by adding `\usepackage{ifpdf}` before `\usepackage[<options>]{songs}`.

The code fails because of the recently added

```latex
\IfFileExists{ifpdf.sty}{\RequirePackage{ifpdf}\ifpdf\SB@pdftrue\fi}{
  \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined\else
    \ifx\pdfoutput\relax\else
      \ifnum\pdfoutput<\@ne\else
        \SB@pdftrue
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

In the past only the “false” branch was used. The problem is that the “true” branch is placed inside a conditional. Namely, the definition reads

```latex
\long\def \IfFileExists#1#2#3{%
  \openin\@inputcheck#1 %
  \ifeof\@inputcheck
    \ifx\input@path\@undefined
      \def\reserved@a{#3}%
    \else
      \def\reserved@a{\@iffileonpath{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
    \fi
  \else
    \closein\@inputcheck
    \edef\@filef@und{#1 }%
    \def\reserved@a{#2}%
  \fi
  \reserved@a}
```

Since `ifpdf.sty` is found in all recent full TeX distributions, the `\ifeof` test returns false, so the line with `\@iffileonpath{#1}{#2}{#3}` is skipped. In doing so, TeX still takes notes of conditionals: since it is skipping

```latex
\@iffileonpath{ifpdf.sty}{\ifpdf\SB@pdftrue\fi}{...}
```

the `\fi` is considered as matching `\ifx\input@path\@undefined`, because `\ifpdf` has not yet been defined as a conditional.

The code should be, if the author is fussy about providing a (not so good) test in case `ifpdf.sty` is not found,

```latex
\IfFileExists{ifpdf.sty}{\RequirePackage{ifpdf}\csname ifpdf\endcsname\SB@pdftrue\csname fi\endcsname}{
  \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined\else
    \ifx\pdfoutput\relax\else
      \ifnum\pdfoutput<\@ne\else
        \SB@pdftrue
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
```